# Open any navigation app via intent from my app to build route

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

There is an android app that deals with coordinates. In some cases it is necessary to build a route to a coordinate. I do not consider it necessary to implement navigation within my app. I think opening the installed navigator on the phone is a good idea. But I'm a little confused that there is no common interface to launch the navigation app in android. For example I found how to start the navigation in Google maps, but it is not meet my needs, because offline Google maps is limited in size. I need to download  at least one country maps. Restriction of Google maps do not allow  it to do.

The most suitable I found MapsMe maps. By I don't found how to start navigation in them from my app via intent.
So I have a few questions:

**1) How can I start navigation in MapsMe using the intent? For example, I can start navigating in google maps as follows**

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+dAddress);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri); mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

**2) Maybe there are other good maps with offline navigation in addition to MapsMe ?**